# Getting a list from Django into Javascript as an array

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a python list generated by my views.py in Django, and I would like to pass it to javascript in my HTML template.
I cannot seem to get it into javscript as an array... I need to evaluate if the list/array contains certain numbers, but it is coming over as a string.

I am passing the list to my HTML template like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(dashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    mylist = [10,22,33,45]
    context['mylist'] = mylist
    return context
```

When I use:

```
<h1 id = "list"> {{mylist}}</h1>
```

it shows up on the browser as 
it shows up as [10,22,33,45]

Then in my template I am using javascript I have:

```
var mylist = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML;
for(i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++){
    console.log(mylist[i])
};
```

this returns in the console:

```
'
[
1
0
,

2
2
........
```

I want:

```
10
22
33
45
```

I have tried to convert to JSON in python, and parse it in javascript, but can't seem to convert this string to an array, or keep getting errors.
Any ideas for the best method here?

Comment: print values of  `mylist = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML;` on console and post it

Answer (score 23):

If you are absolutely certain your list is safe, (by that I mean it never, ever includes anything entered by a user), it is very simple.

In your view:

```
context={"my_list": ["item1", "item2"]}
```

In your template:

```
{{ my_list|safe }}
```

Renders as:

```
['item1', 'item2']
```

For example:

```
{{ my_list|safe }}.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

Impressively, if you pass a string with an apostrophe, Django automatically changes the quote types, so

```
context = {"my_list": ["item1", "it'em2"]}
```

renders as (note the double-quotes):

```
['item1', "it'em2"]
```

so

```
{{ my_list|safe }}.forEach
```

still works (tested on Django 3.2.6).

Even this works:

```
context = {"my_list": ["item1", "it'em\"2"]}
```

renders as:

```
['item1', 'it\'em"2']
```

so

```
{{ my_list|safe }}.forEach
```

*still* works.

However, as I said at the top, if your list might include input from a user, I still wouldn't trust this approach.

==

EDIT: Now this is the highest answer, I wanted to add a safer approach to make it easier to be fully safe. This is interesting from [django-argonauts](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-argonauts), although I'm not a security expert so couldn't confirm the approach:

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def jsonify(json_object):
    """
    Output the json encoding of its argument.
    This will escape all the HTML/XML special characters with their unicode
    escapes, so it is safe to be output anywhere except for inside a tag
    attribute.
    If the output needs to be put in an attribute, entitize the output of this
    filter.
    """

    json_str = json.dumps(json_object)

    # Escape all the XML/HTML special characters.
    escapes = ["<", ">", "&"]
    for c in escapes:
        json_str = json_str.replace(c, r"\u%04x" % ord(c))

    # now it's safe to use mark_safe
    return mark_safe(json_str)
```

Then in the template:

```
{% load jsonify %}
{{ value|jsonify }}
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, are you able to elaborate on what circumstances would cause this to be a bad idea when using user input? For example, if a user passed in `SomeModel.objects.all().delete()` would delete the table in theory, but this would get caught by the JSON.parse first, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hi Matt, no I am not, I couldn't think of anything myself. I put the warning because I *guess* the parsing here would not be done with security in mind, whereas the escaping that `|safe` disables would. The issue is not Python code injection, the issue is JavaScript injection that, if hacked, could load content from a malicious site into your webpage, eg, sniping passwords, mining bitcoin or something in your users' browsers.

Comment: `{{ my_list|safe }}.forEach` isn't valid javascript in a script tag...

Comment: @AlxVallejo your comment isn't clear - you would need to know the JavaScript `forEach` command syntax.

Answer (score 7):

In views you can make your object as a JSON object:

```py
import json

mylistraw = [10,22,33,45]
mylist = json.dumps(mylistraw)
context = {''mylistjson': mylist}
```

Now you can use your object in JavaScript:

```js
var mylist = JSON.parse("{{mylistjson}}")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `tojson` tag to convert python list to js array.

It will be like -

```
var mylist = {{mylist|tojson}};
for(i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++){
    console.log(mylist[i])
};
```

Try it and let me know if any problem occurs.

Comment: tojson is not known by django?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/search/?q=tojson

Answer (score 3):

Django has the `json_script` template tag that addresses XSS vulnerabilities by escaping the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters.

[Django `json_script` docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a simple way is to send the list as string `','.join(mylist)`. And then in your templates, you could simply use `split(',')` in `js`.

views

```
mylist = [10,22,33,45]
context['mylist'] = ','.join([str(i) for i in mylist])
```

html & js

```
var mylist = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML;
mylist = mylist.split(',')
for(i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++){
    console.log(mylist[i])
};
```

Or in case your js is in the template as well

```
var mylist = '{{mylist}}'.split(',');
for(i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++){
    console.log(mylist[i])
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - This is close to working, but when I iterate through the object, the first and last items have square brackets as part of their value. eg: [10 is the value of first iterable.

Answer (score -1):

Set the list value in JavaScript and not HTML.

```
<script>
var mylist = {{mylist}};
for(i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++){
    console.log(mylist[i])
};
<\ script>
```

You need to do this in your HTML template file and not in an external JS file.